# compgen: not found ls: cannot access /usr/bin/convert

Tags: linux, wordpress, bash, shell

My server is very slow right now. I asked my provider to check whats wrong and i got this:

```
root@Pixel:~# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log 
sh: 1: compgen: not found 
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/convert: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/convert: No such file or directory
sh: 1: compgen: not found 
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/convert: No such file or directory 
ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/convert: No such file or directory
sh: 1: compgen: not found 
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/convert: No such file or directory 
ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/convert: No such file or directory 
sh: 1: compgen: not found
```

and that apache is consuming CPU.
We are using *Wordpress* with woocommerce on our site

*any fix?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a program, or add-on to wordpress, trying to use ImageMagick convert program for image manipulation. But ImageMagick is not installed, so you need to install it no doubt.

If you have SSH access, I would suggest:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Let me know if this is not an option or doesn't help.